# SQL Server Insert with no specified columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I have a table with an auto-generated ID column (and that's all!)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmailGroup](
    [EmailGroupGuid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_EmailGroup] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EmailGroupGuid] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmailGroup] 
    ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_EmailGroup_EmailGroupGuid]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [EmailGroupGuid]
```

I want to INSERT into this table and extract the generated ID. but, I can't work out if it's possible.  It seems to complain about the lack of values/columns.

```
DECLARE @Id TABLE (Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

INSERT INTO EmailGroup
OUTPUT inserted.EmailGroupID INTO @Id
```

Is there any way to do this?  I mean I *could* add a dummy column to the table and easily do this:

```
INSERT INTO EmailGroup (Dummy)
OUTPUT inserted.EmailGroupID INTO @Id
VALUES (1)
```

however I don't really want to.
I could also specify my own ID and insert that, but again, I don't really want to.

Comment: Why not just use an auto increment column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though I'm not sure why would you need such a table, the answer to your question is to use the keyword `DEFAULT`:

```
INSERT INTO EmailGroup (EmailGroupGuid)
OUTPUT inserted.EmailGroupGuid INTO @Id
VALUES(DEFAULT);
```

Another option is to use `DEFAULT VALUES`, as shown in Pawan Kumar's answer.

The key difference between these two options is that specifying the columns list and using the keyword `default` gives you more control.
It doesn't seem much when the table have a single column, but if you will add columns to the table, and want to insert specific values to them, using `default values` will no longer be a valid option.

From Microsoft Docs on [`INSERT` (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

DEFAULT

> Forces the Database Engine to load the default value defined for a column.
>   If a default does not exist for the column and the column allows null values, NULL is inserted.
>   For a column defined with the **timestamp** data type, the next timestamp value is inserted.
>   DEFAULT is not valid for an identity column.

DEFAULT VALUES

> Forces the new row to contain the default values defined for each column.

So as you can see, `default` is column based, while `default values` is row based.

Comment: Is this possible with a SELECT as the source of inserted values?

Comment: @mr.ta I'm not sure because I've never tried it. My guess would be no, but I might be wrong and it's an easy thing to check. (Not so easy when writing on the cellphone, though ...)

Comment: Couldn't find anything in the docs nor online. I guess the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

Please use this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmailGroup]
(
    [EmailGroupGuid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_EmailGroup] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EmailGroupGuid] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmailGroup] 
    ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_EmailGroup_EmailGroupGuid]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [EmailGroupGuid]

DECLARE @Id TABLE (Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

INSERT INTO EmailGroup 
OUTPUT inserted.EmailGroupGuid INTO @Id DEFAULT VALUES

SELECT * FROM @Id
```

last 3 OUTPUTs from my Laptop

```
--92832040-7D52-E811-B049-68F728AE8695
--2B6ADC5F-7D52-E811-B049-68F728AE8695
--0140AF66-7D52-E811-B049-68F728AE8695
```